# How to take in consideration object re-creation when mainlooping on Tkinter?

Tags: python, class, object, tkinter

When assigning a variable to an object of any class and launching Tkinter mainloop(), my button which use a method of this object seems to always use the first object created even after successfully replacing the variable with a new object of this class.

The same functions called without buttons on a tkinter interface but in the shell perfectly works as well, but it just seems that the button which executes the method on the variable doesn't take in consideration the new object assigned to the variable.

```
from tkinter import *

class test():
    def __init__(self):
        print('Object id in init is: ', id(self))
    def method(self):
        print('Object id in his method is: ',id(self))

print('We start with a new object defined in main')     
obj=test()

def new():
    print('Replacing the object with a new object')
    global obj
    obj=test()
    return

def display():
    print('Object id in main is: ',id(obj))
    return

root=Tk()
frame=Frame(root)
frame.pack()
n=Button(frame, text='new obj', command=new)
n.pack()
p=Button(frame, text='print_id_obj', command = display)
p.pack()
m=Button(frame, text='obj.method', command = obj.method)
m.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

When clicking on the button `p` then `m`, I have the good id for my object at first (which is perfectly normal), but when clicking on `n` to create a new object, first a new id is displayed thanks to the `__init__` function, then when clicking on `p` I have also the good new id, but when clicking on `m`, the id displayed is the one of the first object which should have been erased by this time, as if the button method definition stored the first object assigned to `var` and keeps using it when clicked as long as `mainloop()` runs.

When closing the `tkinter` window and typing `var.method()` in the shell, I have again the good new id, and as well when performing manually this sequence of actions directly in the shell without using `tkinter`, I have 3 times my first id then 3 times my new id which is what I would expect when clicking my buttons. Try my code to see what I mean if you didn't understand.

Comment: Change the command to `m=Button(frame, text='obj.method', command=lambda: obj.method())` which will create a `lambda` function that uses the current value of `obj` when it's called. The way you have it, the value when the `Button` is created is always being used.

Comment: Perfectly works, thanks.